# python get-pip.py return invalid syntax form shutil.py

Tags: python-3.x, pip, windows-7-x64, python-3.3, shutil

Ok I need help here.

I have windows 7, and i'm stuck with Python 3.3 because my company sucks
I have been trying to install pip via

> python get-pip.py

I am using the get-pip.py from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py which is the re-direct from the pip python page.

When I go to the command prompt to install this, I keep getting the same error message

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 25, in(module)
     import shutil
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\shutil.py", line 85
     def copyfile(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks(True):
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have checked shutil against the source code and my code is not different.   Can someone please help here, I can't find anything that will make this issue go away.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way:
Try this in powershell:

```
> (Invoke-WebRequest https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py).Content | python -
```

Source: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/3.3#windows-7-or-graphical-install

Then you can do this: `easy_install pip3`